# What is a schema? (relating to Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, schema

In Visual studio, I came across the option: "Validate Schemas", what does this mean in context to a Visual Studio project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML schema validation. So it's actually related to XML, and VS enables you to validate it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560392%28v=bts.20%29.aspx

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/